# php paypal class for express checkout

Tags: php, api, paypal, checkout

I'm using (trying to use) paypal class described here http://blog.moorberry.biz/2010/04/paypal-nvp-api/

However it doesn't seem to pass any data to paypal in my case. For example specifying

```
$paypal = new SetExpressCheckout("50.00"); 
$paypal->setNVP("ADDRESSOVERRIDE", 1);
$paypal->setNVP("NAME", "John");
$paypal->setNVP("SHIPTOSTREET", "Some Street");
$paypal->setNVP("SHIPTOCITY", "London");
$paypal->setNVP("SHIPTOCOUNTRY", "UK");
$paypal->getResponse();
```

doesn't affect paypal and when I logged in into it during the process, it defaults to Test User 1 Main Street address. It also doesn't seem to pass AMT value correcty (current purchase stays empty)

If that class is proved to work wrong from any reason, can you provide an example of different class or code? I'm puzzled with this and cannot understand the whole process in 100%.

Comment: I'm sure you include PayPal class. Can you show the lines of code where you initialize the PayPal object, where you get the response, and what the response is?

Comment: I added init and get response above. It's the simpliest starting code possible to connect to paypal basically. I just wonder why (perhaps I oversight something) is the amount (50.00) not displaying  under 'current purchase' and why address is not getting overriden

Comment: To throw out some additional ideas, is it possible if you add an overridden street, city, and country, you must also add other details, such as `SHIPTOZIP`, `SHIPTONAME`, `COUNTRYCODE`? And, from what I see on the link you provided, its `SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME` instead of just `SHIPTOCOUNTRY`, and `FIRSTNAME` and `LASTNAME` instead of just `NAME`. I understand you can add custom specifications, but (I think) PayPal still only accepts certain parameters for purchasing. Take a look at the default values in `etc/NVP/PayPalNVP.ini` and match those names from their NVPs to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Are you in sandbox mode? If you're in sandbox mode, the default values will replace/substitute empty values that you did not provide, and PayPal *MAY* will respond with success since the credentials don't have to be verified.

Comment: @Chase I'm looking at setcheckout parameters and there's no FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME, it's SHIPTONAME. I will try providing all the fields. There's still that problem of the 'current purchase' not displaying provided AMT

Comment: @Chase let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1375/discussion-between-vault-boy-and-chase)

Comment: I would try replicating the response array given in the link you provided. That is where I found the NVPs that are returned in PayPal's response of the checkout details. Good luck!